# Pairing two Android devices to a third device using Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, ioexception

I am doing an Android application where I need 2 devices or more to be able to connect to one device via Bluetooth. The code to connect two devices together in a peer-to-peer form works, but when I try to connect another I get an IOException saying "Connection refused" because the Socket is closed and as such, is unable to complete pairing. The error is shown below.

```
Socket closed. Unable to complete pairing.
java.io.IOException: Connection refused
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connectNative(Native Method)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:216)
    at com.ablueworld.androidgridcomputingframework.BluetoothManager$ConnectAsyncTask.doInBackground(BluetoothManager.java:270)
    at com.ablueworld.androidgridcomputingframework.BluetoothManager$ConnectAsyncTask.doInBackground(BluetoothManager.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Could not connect to this device
```

I've then read that it needs to have a different UUID for each connection, is that right? Anyway, I've written my code as shown below, taking a different UUID from an array for each new connection.

```
    // Unique UUID for this application
    private static int indexUUID = 0;
    private static final UUID[] MY_UUID_SECURE = {UUID.fromString("98b97e6b-62ff-4a36-a81b-82256fd1d168"),
                                                  UUID.fromString("98b97e6b-62ff-4a36-a81b-82256fd1d169"),
                                                  UUID.fromString("98b97e6b-62ff-4a36-a81b-82256fd1d170"),
                                                  UUID.fromString("98b97e6b-62ff-4a36-a81b-82256fd1d171"),
                                                  UUID.fromString("98b97e6b-62ff-4a36-a81b-82256fd1d172")};
    private static final String NAME_SECURE = "GridFrameworkSecure";

    /**
     * Method to connect securely to Bluetooth device using it's MAC address
     * @param macAddress valid Bluetooth MAC address
     */
    public boolean connectSecurelyToDevice(BluetoothAdapter btAdapter, String macAddress){
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress);
        ConnectAsyncTask connectTask = new ConnectAsyncTask();
        BluetoothSocket deviceSocket = null;
        try {
            deviceSocket = connectTask.execute(device).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        if(deviceSocket!=null){
            if(serverBluetoothNode==null){
                try {
                    serverBluetoothNode = new BluetoothNode(deviceSocket);
                    Log.i("bluetooth manager", "You are now a slave node.");


                    return true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("bluetooth manager", "You already have a master.");
                return false;
            }
        } else return false;
    }

    /**
     * Method to allow this Bluetooth device to accept connection from another Bluetooth device
     */
    public void allowSecureConnectionFromRemoteDevice(BluetoothAdapter btAdapter){
        AcceptConnectionAsyncTask acceptTask = new AcceptConnectionAsyncTask();
        acceptTask.execute(btAdapter);
    }

    private class ConnectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<BluetoothDevice, Void, BluetoothSocket> {

        @Override
        protected BluetoothSocket doInBackground(BluetoothDevice... params) {
            BluetoothDevice device = params[0];
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID_SECURE[indexUUID]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Bluetooth Pairing", "create() failed", e);
            }

            Log.i("Bluetooth Pairing", "BEGIN ConnectThread SocketType: Secure");

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                socket.connect();
                Log.i("bluetooth manager", "You have connected a slave node to this one.");

                return socket;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Bluetooth Pairing", "Socket closed. Unable to complete pairing.", e);
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    socket.close();
                    indexUUID++;
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.e("Bluetooth Pairing", "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

    private class AcceptConnectionAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<BluetoothAdapter, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(BluetoothAdapter... params) {
            BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket = null;
            String socketType = "Secure";

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {
                serverSocket = params[0].listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE, MY_UUID_SECURE[indexUUID]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Accept Bluetooth Pairing Thread", "Socket Type: " + socketType + "listen() failed", e);
                indexUUID++;
            }

            Log.d("Accept Bluetooth Pairing Thread", "Socket Type: " + socketType +
                    "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
            while (true) { //mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                try {
                    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                    // successful connection or an exception
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    Log.i("Slave", "server socket found");                    

                    // If a connection was accepted
                    if (socket != null) {
                        BluetoothNode node = null;
                        try {
                            node = new BluetoothNode(socket);
                            Log.i("connected to", node.getDeviceInformation());
                            slaveBluetoothNodes.add(node);

                            indexUUID++;
                    serverSocket = params[0].listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE, MY_UUID_SECURE[indexUUID]);

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                            indexUUID++;
                            serverSocket = params[0].listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE, MY_UUID_SECURE[indexUUID]);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Accept Bluetooth Pairing Thread", "Socket Type: " + socketType + "accept() failed", e);

                    try {
                        indexUUID++;
                        serverSocket = params[0].listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE, MY_UUID_SECURE[indexUUID]);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        Log.e("Accept Bluetooth Pairing Thread", "Socket Type: " + socketType + "listen() failed", e1);
                    }
                }


            }
        }

    }
```

But even so, I get a different error on the third mobile which I'm trying to connect to one that has already a working Bluetooth connection to a second device, as shown below.

```
 Socket closed. Unable to complete pairing.
 java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:406)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:217)
    at com.ablueworld.androidgridcomputingframework.BluetoothManager$ConnectAsyncTask.doInBackground(BluetoothManager.java:270)
    at com.ablueworld.androidgridcomputingframework.BluetoothManager$ConnectAsyncTask.doInBackground(BluetoothManager.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
 Could not connect to this device
```

Can anybody help figure this out? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try calling `cancelDiscovery()` on your `BluetoothAdapter` before creating the socket connection. This might solve your problem on the `java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed` that you are getting.

Comment: I'm already turning Bluetooth Discovery off just before doing the connection.

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515572/service-discovery-failed-from-android-bluetooth-insecure-rfcomm

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the solution to my problem.

In the method to listen then make the connection, I've written it this way:

```
UUID[] MY_UUID_SECURE = {UUID.fromString("98b97e6b-62ff-4a36-a81b-82256fd1d168"),
                                                  UUID.fromString("98b97e6b-62ff-4a36-a81b-82256fd1d169"),
                                                  UUID.fromString("98b97e6b-62ff-4a36-a81b-82256fd1d170"),
                                                  UUID.fromString("98b97e6b-62ff-4a36-a81b-82256fd1d171"),
                                                  UUID.fromString("98b97e6b-62ff-4a36-a81b-82256fd1d172")};

BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket = null;
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            try {
                // Listen for all UUIDs in array
                for (int i = 0; i < MY_UUID_SECURE.length; i++) {
                    serverSocket = btAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE, MY_UUID_SECURE[i]);
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    if (socket != null) {
                        BluetoothNode node = null;
                        node = new BluetoothNode(socket);
                        Log.i("connected to", node.getDeviceInformation());
                        slaveBluetoothNodes.add(node);

                        // add node to database
                        databaseManager.insertToGridTree(node.getDeviceAddress(), "slave", "active", node.getDeviceName());
                    }                       
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Accept Bluetooth Pairing Thread", "accept() failed", e);
            }
```

And the method for the slave devices to connect to the master:

```
    BluetoothDevice device = params[0];
    BluetoothSocket socket = null;

    Log.i("Bluetooth Pairing", "BEGIN ConnectThread SocketType: Secure");

    // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
    // given BluetoothDevice
    for(int i=0; i<MY_UUID_SECURE.length; i++){
        try {
            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID_SECURE[i]);
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            socket.connect();
            Log.i("bluetooth manager", "You have connected a slave node to this one.");

            return socket;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Bluetooth Pairing", "create() failed", e);
            Log.i("Bluetooth Pairing", "trying another UUID");
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e("Bluetooth Pairing", "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
            }
        }
    }
```

This project helped me figure this out: https://github.com/polyclef/BluetoothChatMulti

Hope this helps anyone having the same issue. :)